# Notify which invocation was made without connection with Reachability

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I need to setup some initial data when my app starts. I have this method named `loadData()` which makes several invocations inside it that requiere internet connection. My code looks something like this:

```
func setup() {
  if reachability.isReachable() {
     // If there is connection, we setup the initial data
     loadData()
  } else {
    //If there is no connection, wait for a notification 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to start notifier")
    }
 }
}

func loadData() {
  loadA()
  loadB()
  loadC()
  ..
  loadZ()
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
  if reachability!.isReachable() {
    loadData()
    reachability!.stopNotifier()
   }
}
```

This lets me handle the case where there is no connection before starting `loadData()`. However, if the connectivity is lost, for example, during `loadC()`, then I won't be able to add a notification so that I can load the missing data later. How can I achieve this?

Comment: how do you want to achieve it? how about adding all your items to a queue so you can suspend it and add dependencies between them ?

Comment: @Wain something like that seems right, how would I do it?

Comment: Look at the nsoperation talk from the last wwdc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is inside your load functions. Because of the internet connection requirements, I think you are using some communication with servers. 
In this case, you can check the response code, and make a delegate that alert your class, if something goes wrong. (after that you can recall the failed functions)

Comment: Thanks @Peter, how would you "recall the failed functions"? Keep a flag of each function?